# Are subdirectories included in `bigquery load`?

Tags: google-bigquery

In Google Storage I have a bucket with one folder with files, and a subfolder with the same kinds of files, like this:

```
bucket1
|_ folder1
|  |_ fileD.csv
|  |_ fileE.csv
|_ fileA.csv
|_ fileB.csv
|_ fileC.csv
```

When I do `bq load --source_format=CSV my.table gs://bucket1/*.csv`, will it also load `fileD.txt` and `fileE.csv`?

Comment: have you tried to answer by trying above scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is **yes**.

Actually, `GCS` treats both files and directories as similar objects.
It means that the path below, for example, reference objects whose name starts with **gs://my-bucket/directory1/** and ends with **.csv**

```
gs://my-bucket/directory1/*.csv
```

Now lets suppose we have **only** the directory **directory1** inside the bucket **my-bucket**

In this case, any of the paths below will bring the same result:

```
gs://my-bucket/directory1/*.csv 
gs://my-bucket/direct*.csv 
gs://my-bucket/directory1/* 
gs://my-bucket/d*.csv 
gs://my-bucket/*.csv 
[...]
```

Finally, lets suppose we have the directories **directory1** and **directory1_test** inside the bucket **my-bucket**

In this case, lets see how it works:

1. Reference only first directory:

   ```
   gs://my-bucket/directory1/*.csv
   ```
2. Reference only the second directory:

   ```
   gs://my-bucket/directory1_*.csv 
   gs://my-bucket/directory1_t*.csv 
   gs://my-bucket/directory1_teste*.csv 
   gs://my-bucket/directory1_teste/*.csv 
   [...]
   ```
3. Reference both directories:

   ```
   gs://my-bucket/directory1*.csv
   ```

Given that, you should think more about the objects filename and not about directories and sub-directories.